# How can I access the command line arguments in a console application using IHostedService?

Tags: .net, .net-core, console-application, ihostedservice

I can not figure out how to access the command line args in my `ConsoleHostedService` implementation class. I see in the sources `CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` somehow adds it to the configuration... named `Args`...

Having the main program:

```
internal sealed class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ConsoleHostedService>();
            })
            .RunConsoleAsync();
    }
}
```

and the hosted service:

```
internal sealed class ConsoleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public ConsoleHostedService(
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArguments()`?

Comment: It depends on what you are actually trying to extract from command line. Provide an example of the use case

Comment: @Nkosi: I have the feeling *it definitely should not*. I would like to access the args array *as it is*

Comment: @Dai Thx, this will be the backup plan, although probably this is not the .NET intended way, unless there would not have the `CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` called exactly the `main`'s `args`. Also the `Environment.CommandLine` is a monolitic string, of course I can split it by space, but it *would be less error prone* and more compatible if I got the original OS array

Comment: @g.pickardou If you want the args array as is then create a model with a string[] property, initialize the model with the args and add it to the service collection so that it can be injected where needed

Comment: The one passed to configuration is to allow for configuration binding to strong types via the CommandLineConfigurationProvider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#command-line-configuration-provider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's a *built-in* DI method to get command-line arguments - but probably the reason that handling command-line arguments is the responsibility of your host application and that should be passing host/environment information in via `IConfiguration` and `IOptions` etc.

Anyway, just define your own injectables:

```
public interface IEntrypointInfo
{
    String CommandLine { get; }

    IReadOnlyList<String> CommandLineArgs { get; }

    // Default interface implementation, requires C# 8.0 or later:
    Boolean HasFlag( String flagName )
    {
        return this.CommandLineArgs.Any( a => ( "-" + a ) == flagName || ( "/" + a ) == flagName );
    }
}

/// <summary>Implements <see cref="IEntrypointInfo"/> by exposing data provided by <see cref="System.Environment"/>.</summary>
public class SystemEnvironmentEntrypointInfo : IEntrypointInfo
{
    public String CommandLine => System.Environment.CommandLine;

    public IReadOnlyList<String> CommandLineArgs => System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
}

/// <summary>Implements <see cref="IEntrypointInfo"/> by exposing provided data.</summary>
public class SimpleEntrypointInfo : IEntrypointInfo
{
    public SimpleEntrypointInfo( String commandLine, String[] commandLineArgs )
    {
        this.CommandLine = commandLine ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandLine));
        this.CommandLineArgs = commandLineArgs ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandLineArgs));
    }

    public String CommandLine { get; }

    public IReadOnlyList<String> CommandLineArgs { get; }
}

//

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main( String[] args )
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
            .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ConsoleHostedService>();
                services.AddSingleton<IEntrypointInfo,SystemEnvironmentEntrypointInfo>()
            })
            .RunConsoleAsync();
    }
```

For automated unit and integration tests, use `SimpleEntrypointInfo`.

Answer (score 5):

The `CreateDefaultBuilder` adds a `CommandLineConfigurationProvider` to its configuration providers but you wouldn't normally access it directly. Instead, add an `IConfiguration` parameter to your `ConsoleHostedService` constructor and you will automatically receive settings from several settings sources, including command line arguments:

```
internal sealed class ConsoleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public ConsoleHostedService(
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Get the value as a string
        string argValueString = configuration["MyFirstArg"]

        // Or if it's an integer
        int argValueInt = configuration.GetValue<int>("MyFirstArg")
    }
}
```

This does require that your command line arguments follow the prescribed format as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#command-line-arguments):

MyFirstArg=12345
/MyFirstArg 12345
--MyFirstArg 12345

*However...*

If you **really must** get the actual command line args and, if you don't mind relying on the implementation of the default builder, you could do this:

Create a custom `CommandLineConfigurationProvider` class and expose its `Data` and `Args` properties:

```
public class ExposedCommandLineConfigurationProvider : CommandLineConfigurationProvider
{
    public ExposedCommandLineConfigurationProvider(IEnumerable<string> args, IDictionary<string, string> switchMappings = null)
        :base(args, switchMappings)
    {
    }

    public new IDictionary<string, string> Data => base.Data;

    public new IEnumerable<string> Args => base.Args;
}
```

Then in your main program, add it to the lst of existing configuration providers:

```
internal sealed class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => config
                .Add(new ExposedCommandLineConfigurationSource { Args = args }))
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => services
                .AddHostedService<SchedulerWorker>())
            .RunConsoleAsync();
    }
}
```

Finally, dig your arguments provider out of the IConfiguration provided to you ConsoleHostedService:

```
internal sealed class ConsoleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public ConsoleHostedService(
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration is ConfigurationRoot configRoot)
        {
            var provider = configRoot.Providers.OfType<ExposedCommandLineConfigurationProvider>().Single();
            var rawArgs = provider.Args;
            var namedArgs = provider.Data;
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle this unlikely situation
        }
    }
}
```

But for something that can be otherwise done so simply, that seems like a lot of work (and potentially breakable by any changes in the implementation of the default builder).